# Is there a way to emmit a signal when a cell is edited with same value?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qtablewidget

I need to change the font of a cell in a QTableWidget if the user change the text in it, EVEN if the text is the same as the default one.

I used to use itemChanged signal from the table for that kind of things, but here I'm stuck because the signal won't raise if the user type the exact same text.

```py
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("42")
        self.my_table.setItem(0, 0, item)

        self.my_table.itemChanged.connect(self.update)

    def update(self, cell):
        print("update")
        self.my_table.itemChanged.disconnect(self.update)

        font = cell.font()
        if cell.text() == "":
            cell.setText("42")
            font.setUnderline(False)
        else:
            font.setUnderline(True)
        cell.setFont(font)

        self.my_table.itemChanged.connect(self.update)
```

- knowing :

  - default text in the cell is "42"
  - default font is not underline, other one is
- Case 1:

  - User type "3" -> text become underlined
  - User type "42" -> text stay underlined
- Case 2:

  - User type "42" -> text **should** become underlined

Why it doesn't ? :
Because the ItemChanged signal won't raise if the user type exactly the same thing.

Should I use another Signal ? (didn't find any which could match my need)
Is there another way to do so ?

Why does it make sens to try to do so ? :
The user want to make the difference between a value that is the default value and a value that is FIXED to a value (and doesn't care if that fixed value is the default one or not, because the default value may change).
Also if the user want to set back the value to the default one, he can empty the cell.